# How to change the background of a button programatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, button, background-image

I need to change the BackgroundImage of a button on click of another button (In Windows Forms in C#). But I can't find out how to do it!!

I searched on the internet and found many examples and all of them use ImageBrush, ImageSource etc.... but these don't work on my application, it shows me errors every time I Use them.

I read on the internet that I have to add this namespace:

`using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;`

But it shows me an error on the begging which says to add this `System` before `Windwons` and when I add it:

`using System.Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;`

it shows me than the error at `UI` .... I can't figure it out how to solve this!!

Please help me guys!

Comment: Why don't you just simply use btn.BackColor = Color.Green?

Comment: All you found are `WPF stuff`, not `Winforms stuff`.

Comment: You are trying to use a namespace that you can only use in Store applications.  Aka WinRT apps.  You cannot mix that with Winforms.  Use System.Drawing instead, Bitmap class.

Answer (score 3):

To Change Background Image of a `button` there are two ways i know.

1. Add the Image to the resources folder of your project and use.

   ```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       button1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.ImageName;
   }
   ```
2. Use `Image.FromFile();`

   ```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       button1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures) + "//Card1.png");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use solutions for `WPF` in `Winforms`. This will not work.

The class you need is `System.Drawing.Image` (or `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, which inherits from `Image`).

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"C:\myBitmap.jpg");
myButton.Image = b;
```

Be sure to call `Dispose` on your `Bitmap` if and when it is no longer in use.